# How to remove a specific row from QML table

Tags: qml, qt-quick

I am working with QML Tableview, I have created a model to fill data in the rows of QML Table. I am able to fill data succesfull in the table row when i press the “New row data” button, i am also able to remove the rows from the table using “Delete the row” tool button.

Now i am facing following problems:

I want to select the row which will be deleted by “delete the row” button, by using up and down buttons. 
So please tell me how i can select a table row entry using up and down tool button and how i can get the index of the selected row, so by pressing delete button i can delete that particular selected row from the table.

I have tried `Listview.currentIndex` but its not working ?

```
     import QtQuick 2.2
    import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
    import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.0


Item {
id:root
       anchors.fill: parent
       anchors.margins: 8

       Component {
id: comboDelegate

        ComboBox {
editable:true
model: ListModel {
            ListElement { text: "checkbox" }
            ListElement { text: "edit" }
            ListElement { text: "anyotheroption" }
         }
    }
   }



   Component {
id: comboDelegatetext
        Text {
text: itemText
    }
   }


   ColumnLayout {
id: mainLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
spacing: 4


         GroupBox {
id: gridBox
title: "Grid layout"
       Layout.fillWidth: true


       GridLayout {
id: gridLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
rows: 4
flow: GridLayout.TopToBottom

      ToolButton {  iconSource: "../images/window-new.png"
      Accessible.name: "create a new row"
onClicked: {
    myModel.append({prompt: "pmpt", variable:"LINEDIT",tabname:"TABNAME"})
        console.log(ListView.currentIndex)
    }
tooltip: "creaate a new row" }

    ToolButton { iconSource: "../images/up.png"
onClicked:{

    tableview.selection.forEach( function(rowIndex) {console.log(rowIndex)} )
    }
tooltip: "go up" }

    ToolButton { Accessible.name: "Save as"
iconSource: "../images/down.png"
tooltip: "go down." }

    ToolButton {
iconSource: "../images/process-stop.png"

onClicked: {
        myModel.remove(ListView.currentIndex)
            //console.log(tablemodel.currentIndex)
            }
tooltip: "Delete the row" }



            TableView{
id: tablemodel
        Layout.rowSpan: 4
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
alternatingRowColors: true

                      //anchors.fill: parent

                      TableViewColumn {
role: "index"
title: "#"
width: 35
resizable: false
movable: false
    }
    TableViewColumn {
role: "prompt"
title: "Prompt"
width: 120
       delegate: Component {
id: codeDelegate
        TextEdit {
visible:true
text: ""

    }
      }
    }

    TableViewColumn {
role: "variable"
title: "Variable"
width: 120
       delegate: Component {
id: codeDelegate1
        TextEdit {
text: ""


    }
      }
    }
    TableViewColumn {
role: "type"
title: "Type"
width: 200
visible: true
    }
    TableViewColumn {
role: "tabname"
title: "Tab Name"
       Layout.fillWidth: true
visible: true
    }
model: ListModel {

id: myModel
       }
itemDelegate: Item {
height: 20
            Loader {
                Loader {
                    property string itemText: styleData.value
sourceComponent: styleData.column === 3 ? comboDelegate : comboDelegatetext
                }
        }
              }



            }
    }
    }



    Rectangle{
        Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            GridLayout {
                //id: gridLayout
rows: 1
flow: GridLayout.TopToBottom
      anchors.fill: parent
      GridLayout{
id: grid1
columns: 2
         anchors.fill: parent
         GroupBox {
             //id: gridBox
title: "Grid layout"
           Layout.fillHeight: true
           Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
    GroupBox {
        //id: gridBox
title: "Grid layout"
           Layout.fillHeight: true
           Layout.fillWidth: true
    }
      }

        }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is ToolButton a part of your delegate of ListView?

Comment: @Nadarian No, Toolbuttons are just used like the normal buttons in the toobar. Just thinking to create and delte row by clicking.

Comment: can you show element where you use your firstmodel?

Comment: @Nadarian, please ee the edit code

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple as you were not changing the `currentRow` property of your `TableView`

```
....
ToolButton { 
                onClicked:{
                    tablemodel.currentRow++;
                    console.log(tablemodel.currentRow);

                }
            }

...
ToolButton {

                onClicked: {
                    myModel.remove(tablemodel.currentRow);


                }
            }
```

Comment: Still functionality is same its not able to delete the row selected by mouse, instaed it deletes still the  rows from bottom to top order. I tried to use MOuseArea but still not working,`ToolButton {
                 MouseArea{
                 onClicked: { myModel.remove(tablemodel.currentIndex)
                  console.log(tablemodel.currentRow);}}
                    tooltip: "Delete the row" }`

Comment: You mentioned that you want to select rows by pressing up and down buttons. ToolButton has onClicked method that changes the current item and after you selected one you remove it with remove button. Also notice that when you remove for example 2nd item then 3rd item becomes 2nd so you cant look only at index column. Try adding `text:styleData.value` to the TextEdit at prompt column so you can see which columns are actually deleted